# How to access an already initialized firebase app in React-native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

This maybe a very novice question but I am stuck at here. I am a begineer in React-native and currently working with firebase real-time db with react. I've already initialized my firebase app in one screen(login.js). Since I am using firebase 3.X I cannot reinitialize that app again in another screen. How can I access that already initialized app into another screen(register.js)?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am also struggling finding a nice solution.

Comment: Yes, I did @berkayk. Just create another component and init your firebase app in there. Suppose the init file is at **../Config/FirebaseConfig.js**

`import firebase from 'firebase'

     var config = {
           apiKey: "apiKey",
           authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
           databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
       };
   var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
   export default app
`

and after this import it to your file and you can reuse that.

`
import firebase from '../Config/FirebaseConfig.js'
`

Comment: Please, can you add full example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you export Firebase Config

Make sure you have added firebase to your project by `npm install firebase --save`

then create a config file at **./Config/FirebaseConfig.js**

Add the below code in your file.

```
import Fb from 'firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: 'apiKey',
  authDomain: 'projectId.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://databaseName.firebaseio.com',
};

const Firebase = Fb.initializeApp(config);

export default Firebase;
```

After this you can import firebase in any of your component by `import Firebase from 'Firebase';`

Answer (score 2):

And for the modular Firebase Web SDK 9 and up:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: Constants.manifest.extra.apiKey,
  authDomain: Constants.manifest.extra.authDomain,
  projectId: Constants.manifest.extra.projectId,
  storageBucket: Constants.manifest.extra.storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: Constants.manifest.extra.messagingSenderId,
  appId: Constants.manifest.extra.appId,
  measurementId: Constants.manifest.extra.measurementId,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default app;
```

And then where you need it:

```
import app from '../config/firebaseConfig';
```

This is using Expo and 'expo-contants' (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/constants/) to avoid committing your keys to your Github repo. If not using Expo then you can use react-native-dotenv (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv) which does the same for pure react native apps.